# Alfresco Login with google credentials

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, google-authentication, google-authenticator, alfresco-webscripts

I want to login into Alfresco Dashboard with google credentials. I have seen a sample application below.

https://github.com/gdepourtales/share-oauth-sso

but it is not working for me.

I am using Alfresco 5.0 enterprise version. 
I have downloaded the project and i have followed all the steps

I have build the project which was mentioned and deployed the jars.

I have added below snippet in web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <description>Oauth Authentication Support</description>
    <filter-name>OAuthAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ch.gadp.alfresco.OAuthSSOAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OAuthAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OAuthAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/p/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have added the below configuration in share-config.custom.xml file

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="OAuthFilter"> <!-- the condition must always be OAuthFilter -->
        <repository>
            <!-- The host of the Alfresco repository webapp -->
            <host>localhost</host>
            <!-- The port of the Alfresco repository webapp. Put 80 for standard HTTP-->
            <port>8081</port>
            <!-- The protocol to access the Alfresco repository -->
            <protocol>http</protocol>
              <!-- The API access URI. If you use standard Alfresco, this should not change -->
            <api>/alfresco/service/api</api>
               <!-- The admin user who is able to create new users -->
            <admin>admin</admin>
            <!-- The password of the admin user -->
            <password>admin</password>
            <!-- The unique password for all users authenticated with OAuth. Choose one very complicated :) -->
            <user-password>gotpxdKFjA_uxzG5SdGu</user-password>
            <!-- The domains for which incoming user should be restricted to. If blank, any valid email will be accepted -->
            <user-domains>nxc.no</user-domains>
        </repository>
        <oauth-api>
            <!-- The key of your API application -->
            <key>my key</key>
            <!-- The URI from which get the user profile informations -->
            <uri>https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo</uri>
            <!-- The secret of your API application -->
            <secret>my secret</secret>
            <!-- The scope(s) for getting data -->
            <scope>https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email</scope>
            <!-- This is a constant and my be different in future releases -->
            <name>GoogleApi</name>
        </oauth-api>
    </config>
```

and i have started the server but I am not seeing any change.

How I can Know the process of user login to the dashboard.Because everything written in alfresco is a web-script how can i make a google user to login into Dashboard.

Any answer will help me a lot Thank you!.

Comment: Please add things which you have tried,steps which you are following.

Comment: It looks like something has changed in 5.0. [According to author it should redirect you automatically for authentication when necessary](https://github.com/gdepourtales/share-oauth-sso/issues/5#issuecomment-121584398).

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the following project - https://github.com/FlexSolution/SocialLogin. It uses oauth2 to login Alfresco by using LinkedIn account

The video how it works is available on youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dpueBkL-Jo&index=5&list=PLjxSLwMQLhLifbIIC5qkVio8VoakzncXg

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use *Google**2**Api* these days. Also *prompt* setting is missing in your config.

```
        <!-- This is a constant and my be different in future releases -->
        <name>Google2Api</name>
        <!-- Whether to re-prompt the user for consent -->
        <prompt>auto</prompt>
```